# Entity Framework Server Connection timeout?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I Use Entity framework 6 and trying Connect MSSQL Server .
My problem is MS SQL Serve is closed with timeout not set
how to ms sql server is closed set timeout ?
 I Trying `this.Database.CommandTimeut=10` but not working I wait 1 minute

Comment: Are you asking about the command timeout or connection timeout?

Comment: In fact, they both showed not my problem. Problem is to reduce the waiting time for a response when the server closes